# Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, correlation, p-value

I am trying to loop over specific numeric columns from dataframe, the goal is to
extract correlations and p-values using "cor.test" function.

The correlation consists in calculate the linear relationship of
one categorical variable composed of 0 and 1 values against each specific numeric column.

Here's my code so far:

```
## data ##
names <- c("John", "Greg", "Maria", "Josh", "Emma")
categorical_column <- sample(0:1, 5, replace = TRUE)
numeric_column_1  <- sample(1:30, 5, replace = TRUE)
numeric_column_2 <- sample(1:40, 5, replace = TRUE)

sampled_df <- data.frame(names, categorical_column, numeric_column_1,
                         numeric_column_2)


## specific columns ##

numerical_columns <- c("numeric_column_1", "numeric_column_2")


## for-loop task ##

for(i in seq_along(numerical_columns)){
      
       correlation_num_df <- structure(list(
                         
       variable <- numerical_columns,
                        
       correlation <- cor.test(sampled_df[numerical_columns[i]][[i]],
                       sampled_df[["categorical_column"]])[["estimate"]][["cor"]],
                        
       p_value <- cor.test(sampled_df[numerical_columns[i]][[i]],
                      sampled_df[["categorical_column"]])[["p.value"]]
      ),
    
     class = "data.frame",
     
     nrow = c(NA, -2L))
      
   
}
```

Console output:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds
```

How could I know the subset that is out of bounds? And how could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `across` with `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
out <- sampled_df %>% 
   summarise(across(all_of(numerical_columns), 
     ~list(cor.test(., categorical_column) %>% 
             tidy %>% 
             select(estimate, p.value))))

unclass(out) %>%
      bind_rows(.id = 'grp')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  grp   estimate p.value
#  <chr>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1 1        0.408   0.495
#2 2        0.343   0.572
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error and found this post. I tried Akrun's solution, but it didn't help...though it is likely I implemented it wrong

Building on the example above, here's what I tried:

```
## data ##
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

names <- c("John", "Greg", "Maria", "Josh", "Emma")
categorical_column <- sample(0:1, 5, replace = TRUE)
numeric_column_1  <- sample(1:30, 5, replace = TRUE)
numeric_column_2 <- sample(1:40, 5, replace = TRUE)

sampled_df <- data.frame(names, categorical_column, numeric_column_1,
                         numeric_column_2)

###
out <- sampled_df %>% 
summarise(across(all_of(numerical_columns), 
                 ~list(cor.test(., categorical_column) %>% 
                         tidy %>% 
                         select(estimate, p.value))))
unclass(out) %>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'grp')


## specific columns ##

numerical_columns <- c("numeric_column_1", "numeric_column_2")


## for-loop task ##

for(i in seq_along(numerical_columns)){
  
  correlation_num_df <- structure(list(
    
    variable <- numerical_columns,
    
    correlation <- cor.test(sampled_df[numerical_columns[i]][[i]],
                            sampled_df[["categorical_column"]])[["estimate"]][["cor"]],
    
    p_value <- cor.test(sampled_df[numerical_columns[i]][[i]],
                        sampled_df[["categorical_column"]])[["p.value"]]
  ),
  
  class = "data.frame",
  
  nrow = c(NA, -2L))
  
  
}
```

When I run the above I get a "Warning message: Outer names are only allowed for unnamed scalar atomic inputs" and also get the "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds"

What exaclty does the latter error mean?